# Why is it showing res.login is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying [this basic login](https://github.com/sails101/basic-login). The signup works fine but when I login on `http://localhost:1337/login` (when I enter values in the login form and submit, it shows the following error (the URL doesn't change):

**TypeError: res.login is not a function**

I tried to search on the net but couldn't find any solution. Is there any syntax error or I'm using old technology?

Here's the necessary code:

```
module.exports = {
  login: function (req, res) {
    return res.login({
      email: req.param('email'),
      password: req.param('password'),
      successRedirect: '/',
      invalidRedirect: '/login'
    });
  },
  logout: function (req, res) {
    req.session.me = null;
    if (req.wantsJSON) {
      return res.ok('Logged out successfully!');
    }
    return res.redirect('/');
  },

  signup: function (req, res) {
    User.signup({
      name: req.param('name'),
      email: req.param('email'),
      password: req.param('password')
    }, function(err, user){
      if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
      req.session.me = user.id;
      return res.redirect('/welcome');
    });
  }
};
```

Model: **User.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  },

  signup : function(inputs, cb){
    User.create({
      name: inputs.name,
      email: inputs.email,
      password: inputs.password
    }).exec(cb);
  },

  attemptLogin: function(inputs, cb) {
    User.findOne({
      email: inputs.email,
      password: inputs.password
    }).exec(cb);
  }

};
```

**login.ejs**

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="/login" method="post">

  <label for="email">Your email address?</label>
  <input name="email" type="text"/>
  <br/>

  <label for="password">Your safe word?</label>
  <input name="password" type="password"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**routes.js**

```
 '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },
  'get /login' : {view : 'user/login'},
  'get /signup' : {view : 'user/signup'},
  'get /welcome' : {view: 'user/welcome'},
  'post /login' : 'UserController.login',
  'post /signup' : 'UserController.signup',
  '/logout' : 'UserController.logout'
```

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: It's same as the one written on the site.

Comment: On what line and file the error is thrown?

Comment: Don't know. But when I run http://localhost:1337/login it shows this error.

Comment: Please, add at least the code from your login function, but be more specific to know where the problem is. The code should be in your question, not in an external site. You can read over this: [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have edited the detail.

Comment: @VikasKumar You have included `login.js` in the `responses` folder, haven't you? https://github.com/sails101/basic-login/blob/master/api/responses/login.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `res.login` is a function which you are using in login action. I made few changes to your UserController.js file and its working for me now.

**UserController.js**

Serve both the authenticated and non-authenticated views via login action. Use a session variable to track whether the session has been authenticated already. I am using user.name here, you could use any other attribute like id.

```
login: function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'GET' && !req.session.name) {
        res.view('user/login');
    }
    else if (req.session.name) {
        res.view('user/welcome', { username: req.session.name });
    } else {
        User.findOne({ email: req.param('email'), password: req.param('password')})
            .exec(function (err, user) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                if (!user) res.send("User Not Found");
                else {
                    req.session.name = user.name;
                    res.view('user/welcome', { username: user.name });
                }
            });
    }
},
```

**User.js**
I added an attribute name to User model. This was in the form but not in the model file.

```
attributes: {
    name: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
},
```

**routes.js**

Serving both POST and GET requests from the same Controller/Action.

```
// 'get /login': { view: 'user/login' },
'/login': 'UserController.login',
```

Try around these lines and you should be able to get it working. Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: It's taking every email and any password for login. So it's not working actually. It's just redirecting without matching the fields.

Comment: Its giving 'User Not Found' error for me when I try with random email/password. Not sure how is it working for you.